# Cygwin linking is very slow

Tags: c++, linker, cygwin

I have a normal (but rather small) C++ project that uses CMake as its build system, but it has about 30 executables to link. Under linux, linking all 30 takes ~10-20 seconds or so. Under cygwin, it can take 20-30 minutes.

However, this isn't the only project with this problem. Every project I've tried to compile under Cygwin (all CMake) suffers the same problem (although arguably easier to live with, since there are only a few targets to link).

I should also note that 1) compilation times are fine, and 2) this happens on windows 10, both on a virtual machine and on bare metal.

Comment: You might want to try [MinGW-GCC](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fmingw64-x86_64-gcc-g%2B%2B%2Fmingw64-x86_64-gcc-g%2B%2B-5.4.0-3&grep=gcc) instead of bare [GCC](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fgcc-g%2B%2B%2Fgcc-g%2B%2B-5.3.0-5&grep=gcc) in Cygwin.

Comment: True, compilation is much faster under MinGW, but now the libraries I use fail to compile anymore (machine/endian.h not found, etc.)

Comment: Perhaps `sys/endian.h`?  Seems like this is a [BSD-only](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=machine%2Fendian.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) header file.

Comment: Hmm interesting... I wonder why it worked under normal GCC then. I also tried Clang, with about the same results for linking times (as normal GCC).

Comment: Only linking 30 minutes ? Also with huge binaries and tons of shared lib I do not meet such timing. Something is interfering . May be https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Comment: I don't have any anti-malware/antivirus etc. installed (and I disabled windows defender)... I wonder what is the  case.